# Windows 7 login screen doesnt show user and password field

Tags: windows-7, boot, user, login-screen, system-recovery

All it shows is a black background with ease of access, wondows logo and shut down button on the bottom with the mouse cursor controllable, same thing on safe mode. It started when I downloaded a startup sound changer and when I run the program and chose the new startup sound, avast put the program in its virus chest. Its strange because on softonic it said the program was virus tested so I restored it from the chest but I couldn't open it again, it only showed error 65535 even after re downloading and installing. Same error when I tried running a game I got. I logged off and when I tried logging on again the screen I described came up. Windows recovery says I have no restore . Please help.
Edit: I have no idea why and how but I booted with debugging mode and now it works and I dont even need to login...?

Comment: Can you make a photo and post it here?

Comment: @LPchip it's like no user account picture, there will be two boxes to enter the username and password (like Domain log on).

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of a group policy setting.

- Hit Win+R and type `secpol.msc` and Local security policy editor will come.
- Go to Local Policies > security options and then click "Interactive logon: don't show last user name"
- Then disable it and save settings.

If you are using Starter or Home Basic editions then Group policy editor MMC snap in is not available. Then you have to change registry key.

- Hit Win+R and `regedit`.
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` and look for `dontdisplayusername` value and change DWORD data 1 to 0. (OR delete it, I found this key using Process Monitor)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to disable this setting, not enable it. Your registry tweak seems to confirm this.